# How to use convert command in mass, one clean regular expression sweep?

Tags: linux, shell, imagemagick, gd

I have a bunch of images that loo like PHO_123456_12345678.jpg and I want to generate new images called THUMB90_123456_12345678.jpg, this is the command I want to use except I don't know how to do this in bulk.

```
convert SRC.JPG      -resize 90x90^ \ -gravity center -extent 90x90  DST.JPG
```

Is there a way to do it with regular expressions or does it have to be a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see... I think this should work:

```
ls *.jpg | sed -i -e "s~^PHO_~~" | xargs -n1 -i convert PHO_{} -resize 90x90^ \ -gravity center -extent 90x90 THUMB90_{}
```

Comment: Sorry I just got a: sed: no input files

Comment: Um, I think maybe you should take out the '-i' option in sed.

Comment: Cool, that works (I had to also remove my \ in there), but thanks!

Comment: @StephenGross You shouldn't ever parse the output of `ls`, it's only meant to be seen on the screen, not used for other commands as it will break in magnificent ways when you least expect it (files with spaces being a common one.)  The for-loop construct with globbing, while longer, is the correct way to do this

Comment: @SiegeX I'm normally working on Unix, in which case you *usually* can assume filenames don't have spaces. However, you are correct the spaces will screw up that logic. Other than the spaces issue, what won't work in my answer?

Comment: @StephenGross In a Linux env (which this question is tagged) I see spaces all the time. However, there are many other things `ls` breaks on besides spaces, that is just the most common. See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as to why you shouldn't parse `ls`

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be a combination of a regular expression [inside] a shell script.

```
IMGPREFIX='PHO'
THUMBPREFIX='THUMB90'

for filename in $IMGPREFIX_*.jpg ; do
  thumbfilename=$(echo $filename | sed 's/$IMGPREFIX_\(.*\)\.jpg/$THUMBPREFIX_\1\.jpg/')
  convert $filename -resize 90x90^ \ -gravity center -extent 90x90  $thumbfilename
done
```

Comment: With this the script seems to be doing something, but it is not creating any files :(

Comment: @AdamSkiba, I updated my answer above. The regex is simplified. The problem was I was using single quote instead of double quotes to surround the regex. It should work for you now. I am not familiar with the `convert` command, and am only using the format you provided in your question.